# Weather Website With Ajax Using Open Weather Map API Not Returning Data

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, weather, openweathermap

I want to build a website where if I enter a city name I can see the temperature. This is my code but for some reason it is not working! Please help!

First I will show the JavaScript code and then I will show te HTML code.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#submitWeather').click(function(){
        var city = $("#city").val();
        if (city != ''){
            $.ajax({
                url: 'https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=' + city + "&units=metric" + "&APPID=xxx",
                type: "GET",
                dataType: "jsonp",
                success: function(data){
                    var widget = show(data);
                    $("#show").html(widget);
                    $("#city").val('');
                }
            });
        }else{
            $("#error").html('Field cannot be empty');
        }
    });
});
function show(data) {
    return "<h3><strong>Weather</strong>: "+ data.main[0].temp +"</h3>"
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js"></script>

<div class="row">
    <h3 class="text-center text-primary">Enter City Name</h3>
    <span id="error"></span>
</div>
<div class="row form-group form-inline" id="rowDiv">
    <input type="text" name="city" class="form-control" placeholder="City Name">
    <button id="submitWeather" class="btn btn-primary">Search City</button>
</div>
<div id="show"></div>
```

Does anyone know what I did wrong? Please let me know! I used this video to create the website: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6imiFFeDIzE

Comment: I've reduced your code sample to the minimum. Please post reduced code samples to keep the questions nice and manageable. For example, bootstrap has no direct connection to your issue, remove all bootstrap references. Also, don't post your API keys, those are meant to be private.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your show function, it tries to get `data.main[0].temp`. The Open Weather Map API doesn't specify the main field as an array, it's just an object. So remove the `[0]` part because it's not an array and just an object.
You also put your key in the code, so you might want to reset it.
Also, you try to select the input box with the name of `city` but you actually are selecting the input box with the ID of `city`, which doesn't exist. On the input element add an attribute named `id` with the value being `city`.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to dropping the `[0]` you also need to assign `id='city'` to the input.  You are using jquery `$("#city").val()` which was coming up undefined.  I ran tests in codepen and got it working. [check it out on codepen](https://codepen.io/benjaminadk/pen/RMyeVV?editors=0010)

Comment: Thanks a lot! This is how I need it and it does seem to work in codepen but not in my file... I copied exactly and checked a few times now. I test the website by opening the html file as index.html in my google chrome browser. Any ideas?

Comment: @JamesMiller (my answer was first) I copied everything from the codepen to disk and opened the index.html file in chrome and it worked fine. Open the JS console then enter a city into the text box and press the search city button and look for any errors in the console. If it says something about a 404 error, the city doesn't exist.

Comment: I get this when I enter "Paris" for example:

weather.js:9 Uncaught TypeError: $.ajax is not a function
    at HTMLButtonElement.<anonymous> (weather.js:9)
    at HTMLButtonElement.dispatch (jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js:3)
    at HTMLButtonElement.q.handle (jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js:3)

Comment: @JamesMiller you need to import jQuery using a script tag

Comment: Just above </body> I have <script src="weather.js"></script> is that what you mean?

Comment: @JamesMiller I mean the jquery.js file from the web, the slim jquery version doesn't have `$.ajax`