# Unable to display temp, humidity, date and image for 5 day forecast using JS and openweathermap

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I am having a hard time trying to get these 5 blocks to display the date, temp and humidity for the next 5 days. I'm using dayjs and openweathermap and also want the appropriate image to populate. I know for sure my code is wrong , trying to figure out where exactly im going wrong and why. Im new to JS & jQuery. this is the url for openweathermap api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/forecast/daily?q={city name}&cnt={cnt}&appid={API key}

HTML:

```
<div class="col-12 row">
  <div class="col-12">

    <h2 class="h3">`5-Day Forecast`:</h2>
  </div>


  <div class="col-2" style="background-color: blue; border: 1px solid;">
    <p class="dateNow" style="color: white"><img class="dayImage" src="" alt=""></p>
    <p class="dailyTemp" style="color: white"></p>
    <p class="dailyHumid" style="color: white"></p>
  </div>

  <div class="col-2" style="background-color: blue; border: 1px solid;">
    <p class="dateNow" style="color: white"><img class="weatherImg" src="" alt=""></p>
    <p class="dailyTemp" style="color: white"></p>
    <p class="dailyHumid" style="color: white"></p>
  </div>
  <div class="col-2" style="background-color: blue; border: 1px solid;">
    <p class="dateNow" style="color: white"><img class="weatherImg" src="" alt=""></p>
    <p class="dailyTemp" style="color: white"></p>
    <p class="dailyHumid" style="color: white"></p>
  </div>
  <div class="col-2" style="background-color: blue; border: 1px solid;">
    <p class="dateNow" style="color: white"><img class="weatherImg" src="" alt=""></p>
    <p class="dailyTemp" style="color: white"></p>
    <p class="dailyHumid" style="color: white"></p>
  </div>


  <div class="col-2" style="background-color: blue; border: 1px solid;">
    <p class="dateNow" style="color: white"><img class="weatherImg" src="" alt=""></p>
    <p class="dailyTemp" style="color: white"></p>
    <p class="dailyHumid" style="color: white"></p>
  </div>

</div>
```

JS:

```
let currentDay = document.querySelector('.dateNow');




let search = $(".inputValue");

let tempD = $(".dailyTemp");

let humidD = $(".dailyHumid");

let weatherImage = $(".weatherImg");



for (let i = 0; i <= 5; i++) {
  $(weatherImage[i]).attr("src", "http://openweathermap.org/img/wn/" + daily[i].weather[0].icon + ".png");





  $(currentDay[i]).text(dt.local().plus({
    days: (i + 1)
  }).toLocaleString(dt.DATE_MED));
  $(tempD[i]).text("T: " + convertKelvin(daily[i].tempD.day) + "°F");



  $(humidD[i]).text("H: " + daily[i].humidity + "%");

}
```

Comment: Please read [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: That URL did not help

Comment: @Rojo hi there, im new to stack so im still finding my way through, did i write my question in a wrong way? sorry if i sound dumb , just learning

Comment: You're getting there. For the best answers, read [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and [take the tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour)

Comment: Is this helpful? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49602387/weather-website-with-ajax-using-open-weather-map-api-not-returning-data